# Declaring movements to symbols from other classes

Tags: actionscript-3, function, class

I have created three classes in my project (beginning of a game) and I am very new to AS3.

First I have created a class called player which shall contain the movement of ball_A.
Then I have created a class called enemy which shall contain the movement of ball_B.

in my main class I have created references to the player and enemy classes and trying to assign ball_A.x and ball_A.y coordinates according to my player class and the same for enemyclass.

this is my main class.

```
package  
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    public var playerClass:player;
    public var enemyClass:enemy;
    
    
    
    public function Main()
    {
        playerClass = new player();
        enemyClass = new enemy();
        addChild(playerClass);
        addChild(enemyClass);
        
        ball_A.x = playerClass.ball_A_x;
        ball_A.y = playerClass.ball_A_y;
        
        ball_B.x = enemyClass.ball_B_x;
        ball_B.y = enemyClass.ball_B_y;
        
        
        
    }//Public function

}// Class

}// Package
```

this is my player class:

```
    package  {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;


public class player extends MovieClip
{
    
    var leftIsPressed:Boolean = false;
    var rightIsPressed:Boolean = false;
    var upIsPressed:Boolean = false;
    var downIsPressed:Boolean = false;
    var spaceIsPressed:Boolean = false;
    var rightCtrlIsPressed:Boolean = false;
    var speed:Number = 15;
    var vx:Number = 0;
    var vy:Number = 0;
    var ball_A_x:int = 0;
    var ball_A_y:int = 0;
    
                
        
    
    public function player() 
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initialize);
    }
        
        private function initialize(e:Event):void 
        {
            //EventListeners
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initialize);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
        
        }
        
        
        
        
        //Functions
        
        function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
        {
            switch(e.keyCode) 
            {
                case Keyboard.LEFT : leftIsPressed = true; break;
                case Keyboard.RIGHT : rightIsPressed = true; break;
                case Keyboard.UP : upIsPressed = true; break;
                case Keyboard.DOWN : downIsPressed = true; break;
                case e.keyCode = 163 : rightCtrlIsPressed = true; break;
                
            }
            
        }

        function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
        {
            switch(e.keyCode)
            {
                case Keyboard.LEFT : leftIsPressed = false; break;
                case Keyboard.RIGHT : rightIsPressed = false; break;
                case Keyboard.UP : upIsPressed = false; break;
                case Keyboard.DOWN : downIsPressed = false; break;
                case e.keyCode = 163 :  rightCtrlIsPressed = false; break;
            }
            
        }

        function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void 
        {
            vx = -int(leftIsPressed)*speed + int(rightIsPressed)*speed;
            vy = -int(upIsPressed)*speed + int(downIsPressed)*speed;
            
                ball_A_x += vx;
                ball_A_y += vy;
                
                if(ball_A_x >= 530)
                {
                    ball_A_x = 0;
                }
                else if(ball_A_x <= 0)
                {
                    ball_A_x = 530;
                }
                if(ball_A_y >= 370)
                {
                    ball_A_y = -28;
                }
                else if(ball_A_y <= -28)
                {
                    ball_A_y = 370;
                }
                    
        }
            

    //}//Public function
    

}//Class
}//Package
```

I want to make the two symbols in my .fla which is connected to my main class have the functions of player class and enemy class. (didn't show enemy since the code is basically the same)

but when I try to use this code I get this error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
> at player()
> at Main()

I think this is because of my eventListeners returns nothing since they are void. how can I solve this problem without having to write all the movements commands in one class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're referring to 'stage' within Player, before Player is added to the stage. In fact Player is NEVER added to the stage so, as it is, Player will never have access to stage.
In Main, add your Player and Enemy to the stage:

```
addChild(playerClass);
addChild(enemyClass);
```

and in the constructor functions of your Player and Enemy classes, add:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initialize);

private function initialize(e:Event):void {
this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initialize);
... other event listeners here, now that Player is on stage
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i got another error: the private attribute may be used only on class property definitions.

Comment: this is how my constructor looks like now:

       public function player() 
  {
   this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initialize);
   
   
   function initialize(e:Event):void 
   {
    //EventListeners
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initialize);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
   
   }

Comment: I should have pointed out that you need to close your constructor function with a '}' before the initialize function. This should also fix the error with 'private'.

Comment: I've done as you said and now I don't get any errors. but now I only see one of my symbols (ball_B) and it doesn't move when I press my keyboard

Comment: OK, but this is another problem, right? I don't see your ball_A added to the stage anywhere, either. Also, it appears your enterFrameHandler only adjusts the ball_A_x and ball_A_y variables. These values are assigned to the x and y values of ball_A only ONCE, in the constructor function of Main. For the ball to move you will need to update its position every frame. Also, if you have another enterFrame event in the Enemy class, I'd recommend having just ONE enterFrame event in the Main class and updating both playerClass and enemyClass from that enterFrameHandler in Main.

Comment: Yeah I think I understand what you mean, thanks for the help. I'm sorry I can't vote up your answer since I only have 1 rep :(